# Negative values for Krippendorff 's alpha

Tags: spss, ordinal-data, reliability

I am trying to assess the inter-rater reliability for 5 raters about 36 questions. My variables are ordinal.

Am I  doing something wrong? Or what is the meaning of negative values?

Comment: I edited your question to remove the references to SPSS, as they are irrelevant (and asking about how to do things in SPSS is off topic for CrossValidated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kripp Alpha is a chance corrected level of agreement (similar to Cohen's Kappa).

If you have negative values, this means you have less agreement than you would expect by chance.